# timing/waiting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, delay, wait

I am writting a banner rotator and I want it to cycle among few pictures after few seconds. Does jQuery has something for waiting and then calling the callback? I can see the .delay method, but it doesn't seem to have a callback function. Or maybe I should use a browser-dependant function? Or maybe javascript already contains a function that I need?
I am new to javascript :-| .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the native javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){ /* do your stuff */ }, 1000);
```

You can have some fun with mixins:

```
var timeoutCallback = function() {
    this.foo = 5;
}

var scheduleTimeout = function(obj, delay) {
    setTimeout(function(){ timeoutCallback.call(obj); }, delay);
}

var myobj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
scheduleTimeout(myobj, 1000); // myobj.foo becomes 5 after 1000ms delay
```

Comment: Are you sure the `.call` will work? wouldn't `this` point to the `window` object inside the anon function?

Comment: You are right, I have edited the post after verifying it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right about delay `being` the way to go, if what you wish to do is time jQuery effects.

Look at the [jQuery documentation on effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), and pay close attention to how the effects queue work, it's a very nice framework. :)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to start your effect not immediately, but after some time? So right, this is delay() function.

```
$("#test").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
// after 3 seconds element starts to fade out
```

P.S.

But be carefully with delay. For example this code:

```
$("#test").fadeOut(1000).sleep(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

won't work like somebody may think. Sleep will run synchronous with fadeOut but not after it terminates. So If you want to make an effect complete and than make something - you should make by Callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example I can think of and a condensed version of what Joy Dutta already said. It first shows "Please wait" and after 3 seconds "...done!". Throw it into the Firebug console and see what happens :-)

```
$('body').html('Please wait!');
setTimeout(function (){$('body').html('...done!');}, 3000);
```